# Is React.memo() a thin wrapper around useMemo()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In [this article](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2019/03/how-to-usememo-improve-performance-react-table/), the author uses `useMemo()` to memoize a part of the component instead of using `PureComponent` or `React.memo()`. The author claims:

> Applying useMemo to the returned JSX element tree had the same effect as applying the memo HOC without the intrusive component refactor

An [example in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations) also seems to support this approach:

> Conveniently, useMemo also lets you skip an expensive re-render of a child:
>
> ```js
> function Parent({ a, b }) {
>   // Only re-rendered if `a` changes:
>   const child1 = useMemo(() => <Child1 a={a} />, [a]);
>   // Only re-rendered if `b` changes:
>   const child2 = useMemo(() => <Child2 b={b} />, [b]);
>   return (
>     <>
>       {child1}
>       {child2}
>     </>
>   )
> }
> ```

This makes me curious: **Is `React.memo()` just a handy wrapper around `useMemo()`? Does it guarantee the same behavior?**

For example, [another page in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) says:

> If your function component wrapped in `React.memo` has a `useState`, `useReducer` or `useContext` Hook in its implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change.

Is this behavior also *guaranteed* with a child component wrapped in `useMemo()`? What about other functional/nonfunctional properties?

Comment: No I think they're implemented differently? https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactMemo.js